# Create a matrix of 35 rows and 15 columns with numbers from 1 to 4 sampled randomly

Tags: r, random

I am trying to create a matrix of 35 rows and 15 columns with numbers from 1 to 4 sampled randomly.

Can you please help me create it just using the matrix and sample functions?  I am a noob.  Not sure if `cbind` can be used here.

This is where I am:

```
m1 <- matrix(data = 1:525,  nrow = 35 ,ncol = 15)
sample (m1, 1:4, replace = TRUE)
```

I couldn't find what I needed in the R ?help section.

Comment: Thank you guys.  It worked. and we have not been taught set.seed yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You generate a vector by randomly sampling from 1 to 4 with replacement and then converting the resulting vector into a matrix.

```
matrix(sample(x = 1:4, size = 35*15, replace = TRUE), nrow = 35, ncol = 15)
```

This also gives you the option to use other sampling method, like drawing from a binomial distribution.

```
matrix(rbinom(n = 35*15, 3, 0.5)+1, nrow = 35, ncol = 15)
```

Although I am not sure when I would use this compared to the sample() solution above.

EDIT: as @jay.sf mentioned, use e.g. `set.seed(13)` before randomly sampling numbers in order to be able to reproduce your results.

Comment: +1 Perhaps you may want to point out to OP the use of `set.seed`, which is always crucial in the use of random sampling to make the results reproducible.